# Adding items to a List in another class Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, list, listview, windows-phone-8.1, runtime

I found similar problems, but I didn't manage to solve mine.

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime project. Let's consider a class and 2 pages.

The **Item** class contains the properties of the object

```
public class Item
{
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }

    public Item(string fname, string lname)
    {
        this.firstname = fname;
        this.lastname = lname;
    }
}
```

The **MainPage** of the project creates a list of Items

```
public List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
```

and adds the items to the list using the function

```
list.Add(new Item(string1, string2));
```

Then I have another page called **NewItem**. I used this code to add items to the list, but they don't appear (like the code did not execute, but actually it does)

```
MainPage m = new MainPage();
m.list.Add(new Item(string1, string2));
```

Why doesn't it add the item to the list in MainPage? I use Frame.Navigate() instead of NavigationService class to navigate, is this a problem? Thanks!

Comment: You are creating a new instance of MainPage, that has nothing with the one you navigated from. If you want to have the same variable across all MainPages make it *static*, then access `MainPage.list.Add(..)`. Other solution may be to pass a handler of MainPage to your second page and then you will be able to access the variables you want to. Also if you are using list as a source of items for ListView or other UI element it may be better to use *ObservableCollection* which will notify UI automatically.

Comment: @Romasz I've changed it to static and I used an ObservableCollection, now it works, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the first line of:

```
MainPage m = new MainPage();
m.list.Add(new Item(string1, string2));
```

you are creating a new instance of MainPage, which is not the one you navigated from. So any changes made to variables of that instance won't have effect on your previous page. Note also that this new instance will be garbage collected once it's out of scope.

One of the solutions may be to make your `list` a static variable - then you will be able to aceess it from the app just like this `MainPage.list.Add(...);`. More about static variables you will [find at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx).

Other solution may be to pass a handler of your previous page and then access its variables.

Note also that if you use your `list` as a source for UI elements, it may be better to make it [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx), so that it will automatically notify UI about its changes.